how to remove a scheduled task in Putty
I scheduled a task (a SAS job) in Putty for next week, but this task is required to stop.
I tried
killall -9
but it did not work, and the task is still existing there.
Just wonder is there any way to delete this scheduled task in Putty.
thanks!

The following code removes the scheduled task:
at -r taskname


first grap the PID of the job
ps -ef | grep sas

then kill it with
kill -9 PID

replace the PID with the PID you get from the first command

this code can only stop the running section, not the scheduled task which is not running yet
